# How to find presence of a user who is not in a roster?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, strophe

How to find presence of a certain user who is not in user's roster ? I am using strophe. Does finding presence requires users to be in roster ?

Comment: I wouldn't want to be a user if that meant I had to be _in_ your [rooster](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2300160/images/o-ROOSTER-CROWING-facebook.jpg)...

Comment: can you answer now ? :D

Comment: I can't, since I still can't make heads or tails of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by tweaking server configuration, its possible. By using Presence plugin in openfire server, we can do so. The presence plugin is a service that provides simple presence information over HTTP. It can be used to display an online status icon for a user or component on a web page or to poll for presence information from a web service.

This example requests the presence of a user "jsmith" in XML format:

http://example.com:9090/plugins/presence/status?jid=jsmith@example.com&type=xml

Comment: Well, in ejabberd you have a mod_web_presence as well. But it is not XMPP. This this a server related features and happens out of stream.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of XMPP roster is to let the server know who is allowed to receive your presence.

It means that if a user did not approve another user to see the presence by accepting him in his roster, the other user cannot see / get the presence.

That's a privacy oriented feature of XMPP.